# Get list of files that exist in one folder but not another - PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, duplicates

Given 2 directories (DirA and DirB) what's the most efficient way to find a list of files which exist in DirA but do not exist in DirB?

I tried to do this using the jdupes.exe --printunique --recurse -O, however, this has the side-effect of excluding a file that meet the above criteria if there exist duplicates of said file on DirA.

The files may be in completely different subdirectories of DirA and DirB and they may have different names. So the content of the file is the only durable characteristic.

Comment: Please share with us your attempt at solving this problem using [tag:powershell]

Comment: _"So the content of the file is the only durable characteristic"_..  Looks like you need to create lists with both the file's full path and name, combined with the file's Hashcode. Then compare those Hash values to figure out if two or more files are the same or not. Should be a lengthy excercise..

Comment: Yes... It should be a lengthy process... I was wondering if there was a tool or some functionality I didn't know about that might make the problem easier.

Answer (score 0):

in windows, i copied all files in dirB and replaced in dirA. all the files replaced will be selected. without clicking anywhere goto folder's home menu click invert selection. it may help.

Comment: I think that the OP wants to use Powershell

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to compare content of files, you could use get-filehash and compare the hashes.

Something like:

```
foreach ($folder1item in $folder1) {
    $f1hash = get-filehash $folder1item.fullname
    $f2hash = get-filehash ($folder2 | where name -eq ($folder1item.name)).fullname
    if ($f2hash.Hash -ne $f1hash.hash) {write-output "$($folder1item).fullname is different to $($folder2item).fullname"}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the **compare-object** cmdlet to compares two sets of objects. One set of objects is the "**reference set**," and the other set is the "**difference set**."

Using the **Compare-Object** cmdlet
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-7.2

**Process To Compare Objects**

```
Step1 - Folders To Be Searched
Step2 - Search Both Folders For Files To Be Compared
Step3 - See All Compare Output
Step4 - See Only Difference in reference objects

** Step4a - '=>' - Difference in destination object.
** Step4b - '<=' - Difference in reference (source) object.
** Step4c - '==' - When the source and destination objects are equal.
```

**Sample Script To Compare Objects In Two Folders**

```
## Step 1 - Folders To Be Searched
$folder1 = "C:\Temp"
$folder2 = "C:\Test"

## Step 2 - Search Both Folders For Files To Be Compared
$List1 = gci $folder1 -Recurse | Select Name
$List2 = gci $folder2 -Recurse | Select Name

## Step 3 - See All Compare Output
$Compare = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $List1 -DifferenceObject $List2 -property name -passthru -IncludeEqual


## Step 4 See Only Difference in reference objects
##=> - Difference in destination object.
##<= - Difference in reference (source) object.
##== - When the source and destination objects are equal.

$DifferenceInReference = (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $List1 -DifferenceObject $List2 | Where SideIndicator -eq "<=")
$DifferenceInReference
$DifferenceInDestination = (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $List1 -DifferenceObject $List2 | Where SideIndicator -eq "=>")
$DifferenceInDestination
$EqualInBoth = (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $List1 -DifferenceObject $List2 | Where SideIndicator -eq "==")
$EqualInBoth
```

Comment: This only compares on file Name. The OP wants to compare on _content_

Comment: @Theo... "Given 2 directories (DirA and DirB) what's the most efficient way to find a list of files which exist in DirA but do not exist in DirB?" Your overkilling a basic request!

Comment: I don't think so.. This is from the OP's request: _"The files may be in completely different subdirectories of DirA and DirB and they may have different names. So the **content of the file is the only durable characteristic.**"_

Comment: I'm not debating with you. Just saying your code only compares on file names which unfortunately that is not the question here.. BTW. What makes you think the files are all text-based so string matches would help?

Comment: @Theo its a suggestion approach, until clarity is provided ;o)

Comment: @Theo is correct. I'm looking to compare the content of the files. Hence why I tried to use jdupes. Thanks for your help folks!